# Python UTF-8 text arrives deformed to Android

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, utf-8

I want to send UTF-8 text that is stored with ElasticSeach to an application via sockets.

I have a ThreadedTCPServer Implemented, here is the class that should handle the reply.

I have implemented basic string based handshaking to share some info like query was sent and that response will be sent.

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
       es = Elasticsearch()
       #receive query from the client
       query = self.request.recv(1024)
       #Cut off the characters that aren't recognized
       query=query[2:]
       #for testing
       query=query.lower().strip().replace(' ','_')
       print query
       #Send response that query was received
       self.request.send("200...OK\n")
       res = es.search(index="painters",body={"query": { "match" :   {"title" : query}},"size":1  })
       if res['hits']['hits']:
           response = res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['text']
           self.request.send("201...RE\n")
       print response
       response=response.encode('utf-8')
       self.request.sendall(response)
```

On the android side I have two functions one for reading responses and one for reading bytes.

```
    private String getResponse(InputStream is){
        String line="";
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8);
        try{
            line=rd.readLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return line;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            while (bi.read(b,0,1024)!=-1)
            {
                total.append(decodeUTF8(b));
                Log.d("TOTAL",decodeUTF8(b));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total.toString();
    }
```

And here is the function that should decode the string:

```
String decodeUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(bytes, UTF8_CHARSET);
}
```

Problem is Sometimes not the whole string is shown on the android Side,
and when the whole thing goes through some UTF-8 Characters end up deformed (totally different character than sent)

AsyncTask post execute that starts new Activty:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s.contains("ECONNREFUSED")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Connection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReplyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,s);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

New Intent getting the string:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //get message
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String summary = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Example ouput:

Early life (1928â€“1949)

Andy Warhol ("nÃ©" Andrej Varhola, Jr.) was born on August 6, 1928 in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania. He was the fourth child of Andrij Warhola (Americanized as Andrew Warhola, Sr., 1889â€“1942) and JÃºlia ("nÃ©e" ZavackÃ¡, 1892â€“1972), w

As you can see even when sending the query from android to python I get some crap that I need to cut off.

here:

```
       #Cut off the characters that aren't recognized
       query=query[2:]
```

repr(response):

```
<h2>Early life (1928\xe2\x80\x931949)</h2>\nAndy Warhol ("n\xc3\xa9" Andrej Varhola, Jr.) was born on August 6, 1928 in <a href="Pittsburgh">Pittsburgh</a>, Pennsylvania. He was the fourth child of Andrij Warhola (Americanized as Andrew Warhola, Sr., 1889\xe2\x80\x931942) and <a href="Julia Warhola">J\xc3\xbalia</a> ("n\xc3\xa9e" Zavack\xc3\xa1, 1892\xe2\x80\x931972), whose first child was born in their homeland and died before their move to the U.S.
```

Terminal print:

```
<h2>Early life (1928–1949)</h2>
Andy Warhol ("né" Andrej Varhola, Jr.) was born on August 6, 1928 in <a href="Pittsburgh">Pittsburgh</a>, Pennsylvania. He was the fourth child of Andrij Warhola (Americanized as Andrew Warhola, Sr., 1889–1942) and <a href="Julia Warhola">Júlia</a> ("née" Zavacká, 1892–1972), whose first child was born in their homeland and died before their move to the U.S.
```

Comment: You have a Mojibake; decoding UTF-8 data as CP-1252 (the Euro symbols mark this as a Windows codepage, not ISO-8859-1). Since you are clearly sending UTF-8, the issue must be on the Android side, or at the point where the data is created.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `repr(response)` please? I suspect your ElasticSearch data is already corrupted.

Comment: Is that the literal output of a `repr()` call on the `response` variable? That's certainly UTF-8 encoded data, but I'm missing the quotes around the string. There is no Mojibake there yet, so the issue appears to be on the Android side.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I printed repr(response) to the terminal and copied the part that equals the example output, because it is a whole Wikipedia Article it's too long to paste the whole thing here is the end: n\n'
and the start: 'Andy Warhol\n\nAndy Warhol (; August 6

Comment: Right, but I also was looking for the exact output formatting of the type; if it is enclosed in plain `''` quotes then that's fine, if it is enclosed in `u''` then you provided the `repr()` of the value before encoding, etc.