# Android: Fails to decode UTF-8

Tags: android, python, encoding, utf-8

Follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057010/python-utf-8-text-arrives-deformed-to-android)

I am sending UTF-8 encoded string to Android via TCP socket.

I encode it to utf-8 on the python side, then covert to Base64 before sending.

On the receiving side I then decode from Base64 and decode UTF-8.

Then I pass it into a WebView and show it, but the output doesn't match the input.

Also sometimes I get random stuff. I think it has to do with the handshaking I do before sending the 'UTF-8' String.

```
    es = Elasticsearch()
    #receive query from the client
    query = self.request.recv(1024)
    #Cut off the characters that aren't recognized
    query=query[2:]
    #for testing
    query=query.lower().strip().replace(' ','_')
    print query
    #Send response that query was received
    self.request.send("200...OK\n")
    #cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
    #response = "{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, query)
    res = es.search(index="painter",body={"query": { "match" : {"title" : query}},"size":1  })
    if res['hits']['hits']:
        response = res['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['text']
        self.request.send("201...RE\n")

    response=response.encode('utf-8')
    encoded=binascii.b2a_base64(response)

    self.request.sendall(encoded)
```

as you can see I send "200...OK\n" and "201...RE\n" before sending the encoded string.

On the Android Side:

```
 TextIn = getResponse(dataInputStream);
            if (TextIn!=null)
            {
                if (TextIn.equals("200...OK")){
                    publishProgress("Query Sent!");
                    TextIn=getResponse(dataInputStream);
                    Log.d("TEXTIN",TextIn);
                    if(TextIn.equals("201...RE")){
                        returnvalue=convertStreamToString(dataInputStream);
                    }
                    else{
                        returnvalue="FAILURE";
                    }

                }
            }
```

Function for receiving the "200..OK" and "201..RE:

```
        private String getResponse(InputStream is){
        String line="";
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),8);
        try{
            line=rd.readLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return line;
        }
```

Function for receiving the 'UTF-8' data:

```
    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        byte[] temp;

        ByteArrayOutputStream fold=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while (bi.read(b,0,1024)!=-1)
            {
                fold.write(b);
               // Log.d("TOTAL",decodeUTF8(b));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        temp=fold.toByteArray();
        temp= Base64.decode(temp,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return decodeUTF8(temp).toString();
    }
```

Decoding

```
    private final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String decodeUTF8(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(bytes, UTF8_CHARSET);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TextView instead of WebView fixed the problem